# Adding website URL in reference section of report writing

Tags: expressions, writing, non-standard

I was wondering what kind of format is standard or recommended style of mentioning URL of a website in report writing.

What I found in the internet after a quick search was

> Cameron, B (Minister for Corrections, Victoria) 2007, Construction
>   begins on high security unit, media release, Victoria, 28 March,
>   viewed 16 April 2007, http://www.dpc.vic.gov.au.

From [this](http://utas.libguides.com/content.php?pid=27520&sid=219177) page.

But I don't want it to be that complex and there is no such complex information. I only have link and date on which I viewed that site.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends upon how the rest of the report is being written. From your link you are using the Harvard Referencing Style.

From the same website you reference there is also the MLA (Modern Language Association) style, and others. Is a style specified for your report by the recepient?

Comment: @FatherLuke Thank you for response. No there is no style specified.

Comment: Clarity will suffice, I'd wager. Clarity and due credit. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Endnote, it comes with some simple canned styles.

If you want to create your own, the *Chicago Manual of Style* **(14.245)** offers some suggestions:

Include as much of the following as can be determined:

- The title or a description of the page.
- The author of the content (if any)
- The owner or sponsor of the site of the site
- A URL
- A publication date or modification date or an access date if these other dates aren't available

Citations are best relegated to the notes of a paper or to a bibliography if the paper has no notes.

For example:

"Adding website URL in reference section of report writing", *English Language & Usage*, last modified July 17, 2015, accessed July 18, 2015, [Adding website URL in reference section of report writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260496/adding-website-url-in-reference-section-of-report-writing)

The advice seems to be include as much information as you have available or that might be of interest to your audience.